# Android Maps API v2 Marker with custom defined anchor jumps when dragged

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, draggable

I have an Google Maps Android v2 API marker that I have set an anchor at 0.5/1.0. Just placing the marker works fine. The problem is when I drag the marker, on first move it jumps up and to the left up by approximately the height of the image (1.0) and half the width (0.5). It seems like the dragging code of Google does not consider the custom defined anchor.

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().draggable(true)
 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
 .fromResource(R.drawable.blue_flag))
 .anchor(0.5f, 1.0f)
 .position(endPosition));
```

Anyone seen this? Seems like a bug in the dragging algorithm.

Comment: I see it even without the custom anchor position. I am guessing that it is a bug.

Comment: I submitted a bug for this:  http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6132&thanks=6132&ts=1386184057